# d3 Re-center group of elements in SVG

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have an svg that looks like this:

[image]

It's basically a network diagram comprised of nodes and links that has the ability to pan and zoom. Let's say for instance I accidentally drag the entire group off the screen. What is the best way for me to re-center my group so I can see it again?

I've tried to do a transform and changed the scale value, but things will still be outside the view.

```
 this.zoomTrans.scale = this.zoomTrans.scale - .1;
  this.container.attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.zoomTrans.x + ',' + this.zoomTrans.y + ') scale(' + this.zoomTrans.scale + ')');
```

Comment: Well, the original translate is probably `(0,0)`, isn't it? If not, you have to find the center coordinate of your network by going through your points (or your generating algorithm). Calculating a translate from that is trivial. Actually, it's better to calculate the size and make sure that the graph does not go off the screen (using the size of the graph and the size of the window to limit translation values).

Comment: Cool, yeah this works. Pretty obvious now that I've done it. Previously I was assuming I could just scale back until I could see my group again.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations `d3` generates points starting from the origin `(0, 0)` which is also obviously the default translate. Moving back to `(0, 0)` should therefore get your back to a visible part of your chart.

To really center your chart, you need to calculate the center point, which is generally done by calculating the `minX`, `maxX`, `minY` and `maxY` from your points and then calculating `(minX + maxX) / 2` and `(minY + maxY) / 2` and center that point in your window.

A more advanced solution is to track the translation and limiting it in a way that the chart will never go out of the screen. Again, you need the min and max values for your coordinates. The min horizontal translation is then `-maxX` and the max horizontal translation is `windowWidth + minX`. With zoom not equal to 1, it's only about multiplying the limits correctly with the zoom.